# Find a specific field on a site and the set it to “Required” in a EventReciever

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a EventReciever that will be activated when a site gets created. This site have a announcement webpart. When they click on "add announcement", newform.aspx pops up as a dialog and there is a field there that is called Expired I need to make it required, so the field must be used else it prevent the user of adding a announcement.

How can I find that specific field and set it to Required in my EventReciever?

```
<!-- FieldName="Expires"
             FieldInternalName="Expires"
             FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
          -->
```

This is how I have progressed so far:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{

    if (properties.Feature.Parent is SPWeb)
    {
        var web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
            var expiredDate = web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Expires");
            expiredDate.Required = true;
            expiredDate.Update();

    }

}
```

Any kind of tips or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WebPart will probably query a specific list? In that case it's also an option to set the Expires too required on that list.

Your current code will only update the Expires site column in the site, it will not push these changes to the lists using this column. If you were to create a new list after executing your code you would have a list where Expires is required.

However by reading your code my guess is that you actually want to update the current list and all new lists containing the column. In that case you should modify the `expiredDate.Update()` to `expiredDate.Update(true)`. This boolean is an indication to SharePoint that you want the changes pushed down to existing lists. After executing this update you will see that your existing lists also require users to fill out an Expires date.